# Minimizing direction derivative

Tags: calculus, optimization

I am trying to find the direction of a change vector $v$ that minimizes $D_vf(x)$, subject to $||v|| \leq 1$ and assuming $\nabla f(x) \neq 0$.

I wrote the problem as:

$$
\begin{align}
\min_{v} \quad & D_vf(x) \\
\text{subject to} \quad & ||v|| \leq 1
\end{align}
$$

I write the directional derivative as:

$$D_vf(x) = \nabla f(x)\cdot v$$

Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

$$|\nabla f(x)\cdot v| \leq ||\nabla f(x)||.||v||$$

I took the left side of the absolute value inequalities to get to the minimum:

$$-||\nabla f(x)||.||v|| \leq \nabla f(x)\cdot v$$

Given the constraint and that magnitudes cannot be negative, $||v|| = 1$ yields the lowest possible value for $D_vf(x)$ and that value is $-||\nabla f(x)||$

Now for the direction of $v$:

$$\nabla f(x)\cdot v = -||\nabla f(x)||$$

$$ v = -\frac{||\nabla f(x)||}{\nabla f(x)}$$

But I read that $D_vf(x)$ is minimized when the unit vector points in the opposite direction from $\nabla f(x)$ , so shouldn't that be:

$$ v = -\frac{\nabla f(x)}{||\nabla f(x)||}$$

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your work is great until the step where you divided. You cannot divide by a vector. Think about what Cauchy-Schwarz tells you about the vectors if equality is reached.

Comment: I stated the equality at the minimum. By Cauchy-Schwarz the vectors are linearly dependent. Knowing that the length of d is 1 I can get to the correct value of v. I'm having some trouble with the sign but I think I got the idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"I read that ()
is minimized when the unit vector points in the opposite direction from ∇()
,"
$$
\newcommand{bw}{{\mathbf w}}
\newcommand{bv}{{\mathbf v}}
$$
That statement is correct (assuming you want to minimize the value, not the absolute value). To simplify writing, let's write
$$
\bw = \nabla f(x)
$$
Then as you observe, the rate of change of $f$ in direction $\bv$ is $\bw \cdot \bv$.

Let $\bv$ be any vector in that unit ball. Write
\begin{align}
\bv & = \bv_n + \bv_p & \text{ where}\\
\bv_n &= (\bv \cdot \bw)\bw \\
\bv_p &= \bv - \bv_n
\end{align}
Then $\bw \cdot \bv_p = 0$. That means that if $\bv$ is a minimizer, then so is $\bv_n$. Thus we need only consider potential minimizers that are multiples of $\bw$.

Among all vectors $t\bw$ in the unit ball, which one minimizes $\bw \cdot t\bw = t (\bw \cdot \bw)$? Well, because $\bw \cdot \bw > 0$ by hypothesis, the one that minimizes it is exactly the one with the most negative value of $t$ that's consistent with $t\bw$ being within the unit ball. I'll let you take it from here.